# Pellet Hops spilled out of bag in secondary. Advice?

Tags: secondary, hops, dry-hop, troubleshooting

My hop bag came undone in my secondary while dry-hopping and now I have pellet hops directly in my beer. What is the best way to filter out the hops for bottling?

Answer (score 4):

No need to filter.  Just rack carefully from underneath them with the time comes.
Many people dry hop with pellets withou bags.

Comment: Or give the hops time to sink and treat like trub.

Comment: I've read about creating centrifugal force by stirring the beer and all the hops would be drawn to the center, allowing racking to be done from closer to the edge of the bucket. Any truth to that?

Comment: @BrianInBrooklyn I do that after every boil. You should ask that as a full question though. I think we'll get some good responses :)

Comment: PJ, a separate question outside of this post, or as an answer to my question? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Separate question outside the post.

Answer (score 3):

I've never used a bag when dry hopping, I just throw the pellets in. Usually after a week of dry hopping the hops are all at the bottom with any trub/yeast that settled out. I'd say to just rack as carefully as you already probably do.

Comment: I ended up filtering through a strainer into another bucket. I had hops floating, at the bottom, and in suspension; so it seemed to risky bottling through that. The extra step resulted in a nice clear beer.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, the easiest way is to zip tie a large nylon straining bag to the end of the hose inside the bottling bucket/keg and rack carefully.  Anything that gets in gets stuck in the bag.  It has worked flawlessly for me every time, and it doesn't get clogged like the nylon over the racking cane as it has a ton of surface area for the beer to get through.